# how to generate without repeating the combination in R using the function combn() and generalize the code?

Tags: r, combinations

Hy, I have this:

```
list(
myvector_a=c("X1","X2","X3"),
myvector_b=c("X1","X3","X4"),
myvector_c=c("X2","X5","X6"))->mydata
```

**Expected output:** *build manually*

```
list(
  myvector_a=list(c_1_1=myvector_a[[1]],
                  c_1_2=myvector_a[[2]],
                  c_1_3=myvector_a[[3]],
                  c_2_1=c(myvector_a[[1]],myvector_a[[2]]),
                  c_2_1=c(myvector_a[[1]],myvector_a[[3]]),
                  c_2_1=c(myvector_a[[2]],myvector_a[[3]]),
                  c_3_1=c(myvector_a[[1]],myvector_a[[2]],myvector_a[[3]])),
  myvector_b=list(c_1_1=myvector_b[[1]],
                  c_1_2=myvector_b[[2]],
                  c_1_3=myvector_b[[3]],
                  c_2_1=c(myvector_b[[1]],myvector_b[[2]]),
                  c_2_1=c(myvector_b[[1]],myvector_b[[3]]),
                  c_2_1=c(myvector_b[[2]],myvector_b[[3]]),
                  c_3_1=c(myvector_b[[1]],myvector_b[[2]],myvector_b[[3]])),
  myvector_c=list(c_1_1=myvector_c[[1]],
                  c_1_2=myvector_c[[2]],
                  c_2_1=c(myvector_c[[1]],myvector_c[[2]])))->result
```

**This was my closest solution to what I need:**

```
x<-NULL
for(i in 1:3)
  for(j in 1:length(mydata[[i]]))
    combn(mydata[[i]],j) -> result[[paste0(names(mydata[i]))]][[paste0("c_",i,"_",j)]]
```

For example, in Output obtained: result[["myvector_a"]][["c_1_2"]] I couldn't separate as in Expected output: result[["myvector_a"]][["c_2_1"]], result[["myvector_a "]][["c_2_2"]] and result[["myvector_a"]][["c_2_3"]].

**Expected output:**                                                                     **Output obtained:**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way using `lapply` within `lapply` -

```
result <- lapply(mydata, function(x) {
  unlist(lapply(seq_along(x), function(y) combn(x, y, list)), recursive = FALSE)
})
```

[image]

---

Using `list` and `unlist` is done only to get the required structure of the output. If you are not too concerned about it this would work as well.

```
result <- lapply(mydata, function(x) lapply(seq_along(x), function(y) combn(x, y)))
```

Comment: Hi, I ran your suggestion code, but the output you get is different from my Expected output or the image result of your output.

Comment: You mean using the data from your post and using the 1st answer from my post doesn't give you the same output as shown in the image?

Comment: Sorry, the formatting isn't clear in the comments. What does `lengths(result)` return for you? It should be 7 for all of them in this example. I restarted R and checked the answer again. It gives me exactly what I have shown.

Comment: Sorry, I reset mine too, now I do! Grateful

Answer (score 1):

We could use `outer` from `base R`

```
out <- c(outer(seq_along(mydata), seq_along(mydata), 
   FUN = Vectorize(function(i, j) combn(mydata[[i]], j, FUN = list))))
```